# Is the Arrowverse watching order a bit jumbled?

Tags: dc, tv, the-flash-2014, arrowverse, supergirl

So I've been looking at plenty of watching orders for Arrow season 4, The Flash season 2, Legends of Tomorrow season 1 and Supergirl season 1.

As most of you know, there are crossovers but the airing order isn't all that clear.

[SEMI-SPOILER]
In the 18th episode of Supergirl, The Flash appears and helps her do stuff. In the 17th episode of The Flash however, The Flash doesn't even come remotely close to going anywhere near Supergirl, which means that the 18th episode of The Flash should cover this.

Episode 18 of Supergirl aired last week but the 18th of The Flash should air on the 19th of April. Fun fact? Supergirl episode 19 will be aired on the 11th of April. Also Arrow episode 18 will be aired on the 6th of April, which is also before The Flash even remotely reaches the 18th episode.
[/SEMI-SPOILER]

This really confuses me as most watch orders don't even cover these episodes. So what's up? Did the watching order get screwed over like it was back with Arrow season 3 and The Flash season 1?

Is this actually going wrong and if so, what should the actual order be?

Sorry if this is asked like 5000 times before but I can't seem to find any clear answer to what is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anything involving supergirl, is a fun treat, but nothing that really effects either world. so their watching order is a non issue, as super girl is not a part of arrowverse, the creators just thought it would be fun for a cross over

Comment: “most watch orders don't even cover these episodes. So what's up?” — The episodes haven’t aired yet. It’s a bit difficult for people to suggest what order they should be watched in when they haven’t seen them, and thus don’t know what happens in them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite They also don't cover the previously aired episodes. So that's why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Crossovers aren't always flawlessly executed, especially when two different networks are involved.

As you have pointed out in your question the episodes were aired in the following order:

> Flash 2x16
>   Supergirl 1x18 (crossover)
>   Flash 2x17

From watching the episodes it is clear that Supergirl 1x18 actually takes place after Flash 2x17. As to where the crossover actually is set is hard to say, seeing as Flash 2x18 hasn't been released yet. It is also possible that Flash will ignore the crossover, and there won't be anywhere to place it.

Comment: Word of God is that they aired out of order. http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/supergirl-flash-crossover-spoilers-878275

Comment: @nitind - Most of that is common sense, but it's nice to have it officially confirmed.

Comment: @nitind Yeah I figured as much. I also thought it was strange that Arrow 18 would be aired before Flash 18. Usually Flash is earlier.